# Applying to a job directly and through contacting recruiter

Tags: job-search, recruitment

I applied to a job posted on LikedIn and my CV was sent to a recruiter. I did not however agree on anything with the recruiter though (when applying, I did not even know who the recruiter was).  After about a week (today, that is) the recruiter emails to ask if I am interested to work in the UK (the job is in the UK and I do not currently live there).

I checked again the website where I applied (LinkedIn) and saw that the company name is written there, and when looking at the company website I noticed that one can apply directly on the company website.

Since the recruiter seems to be rather slow (he obviously did not send the application or shortlisted me yet), would there be any problem if I apply now directly on the company website?

If the recruiter asks me later, I can tell him I already applied directly but I would be certainly interested in similar jobs I do not know about. Or do I really have something to gain by relying entirely on the recruiter?

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you know for a fact that the recruiter hasn't sent your application to this specific employer? Or are you just assuming that based on their follow up question about working in the UK? Also: you stated that you haven't agreed to anything with the recruiter. Do you know if they have an agreement with the employer?

Comment: Hi, when I clicked 'Apply' on LinkedIn I was sent to another website (totaljobs), where I uploaded my CV and was told that the CV will be sent to a recruiter. I only found out who the recruiter was when I received his email asking if I am interested to work in the UK.  Of course, he might have sent the CV to the company without telling me. On the company website I found this: https://www.fluidic.com/company/current-vacancies/notice-recruitment-agencies/

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything else, it is critical you confirm with the recruiter whether or not they have already submitted you to the company in question.  If the recruiter has already submitted your resume to the company, you should proceed with that recruiter (I was working with two recruiters at once during a job search, and one submitted my resume without permission.  The second helped me improve my resume, and submitted me to the same company with permission - I did not receive the job because the company had two competing resumes, and had already turned me down to the first recruiter based on my unimproved resume.).

From the recruiter's question, it sounds more likely your resume has not already been submitted. If that is the case, you are free to choose either option.

### Using the Recruiter

Using the recruiter may be to your advantage if the recruiter has a good relationship with the company or hiring manager.  It would likely be within their interest to negotiate a good salary, as they usually get paid a finder's fee based on that salary if you work out.  The company is paying the recruiter, however, so you are less likely to be able to negotiate things like moving expenses or signing bonuses.

### Applying directly with the Company

Salary negotiation would be completely up to you.  You won't have a recruiter to push your resume toward the top of the pile.  If your resume stands up solidly on its own, this is not much of a problem.  You will want to have a clear idea of what pay you are expecting - don't forget to take into account cost of living differences between where you are now and where you would move - to make sure you don't accept an offer that doesn't work for your needs.

As the company does not have the added expense of the recruiter's fee to pay upon hiring or retaining you for a certain period of time, there may be more room in their budget to allow for things like signing bonuses or moving expenses.

---

In general, it sounds like you are unimpressed with this recruiter.  If you have a negative impression of them, I would avoid them.  But if you don't believe you would be able to negotiate for the pay or bonuses you should receive to full effect, going with the recruiter may be to your advantage.  If you have doubts of your own negotiating ability, you may also want to consider finding a recruiter that makes a better impression to submit your application to the company.

*Note:* I am in the US.  I know labor laws and common practices are significantly different in the UK and/or Europe, so please take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

It was explained to me by a recruiter that often companies have systems that will automatically reject applicants they get more than once.   So if you submit your resume, and then the recruiter submits it, it will get flagged by the company and removed.

I wont debate the pros and cons of choosing to use the recruiter, thats for you to decided. Choose one or the other.